# Geografical center of region in Google Map API

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get geografical center of region called "Středočeský kraj" in JSON format http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=St%C5%99edo%C4%8Desk%C3%BD%20kraj&sensor=false but it gives me incorrect result. It gives me  "lat" : 49.8782223, "lng" : 14.9362955, but correct is this https://www.google.cz/maps/place/St%C5%99edo%C4%8Desk%C3%BD+kraj/@50.060218,14.4659312,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x470b939c0e8ff2a3:0x100af0f6614a830 (50.060218,14.4659312) How is this possible, that JSON return incorrect data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The data returned by the API isn't incorrect, it's not documented that the returned location for an area will be the center of the area.

Take a look at http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3DSt%u0159edo%u010Desk%FD%20kraj . You'll see there a blue rectangle which marks the bounds of this area.

To get the center of the bounds instead of the marker-location calculate it based on the bounds:

```
new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(49.501336,13.397336),
                             new google.maps.LatLng(50.619099,15.534525))
                              .getCenter();//returns 50.060217, 14.465930(Prague)
```

As it seems you request the address on serverside, you may simply calculate the center without using the Javascript-API:

```
lat:(bounds.southwest.lat+bounds.northeast.lat)/2 
lng:(bounds.southwest.lng+bounds.northeast.lng)/2
```

Note: the result will be the mathematical center, not the geographic center(the returned latitude will differ), but for your use-case it should be sufficient. To calculate the geographical center use the [haversine-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=haversine)

Comment: @DavidHolada mark the answer as correct if it was what you needed